# Namespace components are not referenceable

Tags: xml, xsd, namespaces

Below is my partial XML Schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/Procurement" 
xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/Procurement" elementFormDefault="qualified">

<element name="CountryCode">
    <simpleType>
        <restriction base="string">
            <enumeration value="US" />
            <enumeration value="DE" />
            <enumeration value="JP" />
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>
</element>

<element name="Address">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element name="Name" type="string" minOccurs="0"  />
            <element name="StreeName" type="string" minOccurs="0"  />
            <element name="City" type="string" />
            <element name="PostalCode" type="string" />
            <element name="Country" type="CountryCode" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element>

</schema>
```

When I attempt to validate this Schema I get an error related to the `CountryCode` attribute in the `Country` type e.g.

Error resolving component. It was detected that 'CountryCode' is in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', but components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'file:///C:/Eclipse/workspace/Procurement.xsd'.

I've done some research and have seen similar posts but still can't resolve this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to define a type, you can't use an `<element>`. Just define the type itself:

```
<simpleType name="CountryCode">
  <restriction base="string">
    <enumeration value="US" />
    <enumeration value="DE" />
    <enumeration value="JP" />
  </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

Including this type in your XSD will mean that the type will be in your target namespace. So you'll need to reference it as such:

```
<element name="Country" type="tns:CountryCode" />
```

With these two modifications, your XSD should be correct.